# can i use CLucene and the Cue Sheet Parser together?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, building, ubuntu, clucene

i'm trying to use clucene-0.9.21b and libcue-1.3.0 in Qt Creator on Kubuntu Lucid. **this code is compilable**:

project.pro

```
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -lcue
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/libcue-1.3/libcue
```

main.cpp

```
extern "C" {
 #include <libcue.h>
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 return 0;
}
```

**so is this**:

project.pro

```
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -clucene
```

main.cpp

```
#include <CLucene.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 return 0;
}
```

**but not this one**:

project.pro

```
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -lcue \
 -clucene
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/libcue-1.3/libcue
```

main.cpp

```
extern "C" {
 #include <libcue.h>
}
#include <CLucene.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 return 0;
}
```

the latter generates the following errors:

```
Running build steps for project project...
Configuration unchanged, skipping QMake step.
Starting: /usr/bin/make -w 
make: Entering directory `/home/user/project/project'
/usr/bin/qmake-qt4 -spec /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -unix CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile project.pro
make: Leaving directory `/home/user/project/project'
make: Entering directory `/home/user/project/project'
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/libcue-1.3/libcue -I. -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/sys/stat.h:107,
from /usr/include/CLucene/StdHeader.h:76,
from /usr/include/CLucene.h:11,
from main.cpp:5:
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:88: error: field ‘st_atim’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:89: error: field ‘st_mtim’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:90: error: field ‘st_ctim’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:149: error: field ‘st_atim’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:150: error: field ‘st_mtim’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/bits/stat.h:151: error: field ‘st_ctim’ has incomplete type
main.cpp:6: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
main.cpp:6: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/user/project/project'
Exited with code 2.
Error while building project project
When executing build step 'Make'
```

why is that and how to make it work?

Comment: Why do you put an explicit `extern "C"` around including `libcue.h`? This may explain what is going wrong. I don't know these libraries, but it seems something goes wrong when including system header. The `extern` might be the cause.

Comment: it's necessary as libcue is a C library. it won't compile altogether without extern.

Comment: same result with clucene-0.9.21 and libcue-1.4 in Qt Creator on openSUSE 11.3

Comment: same story with clucene-0.9.21b and libcue-1.4 on Kubuntu Maverick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this time I got a chance to actually try it. Problem seems to be that libcue has a file called time.h in its include folder. So if you compile with -I/usr/include/libcue-1.4/libcue then you end up with libcue's time.h instead of libc's.

This works for me:

```
extern "C" {
 #include <libcue/libcue.h>
}
#include <CLucene.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 return 0;
}
```

and obviously compiling with -I/usr/include/libcue-1.4/ instead of -I/usr/include/libcue-1.4/libcue

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you swap the cue and clucene includes around? It could be a problem with include order and I suspect mixing c and c++ may make include order even more important